# Convert fragment shader (in GLSL) to Metal Shader code

Tags: glsl, metal

The following code needs to be converted to Metal for Xcode:

```
uniform sampler2D emissionTexture;

vec3 light = _lightingContribution.diffuse;
float lum = max(0.0, 1 - (0.2126*light.r + 0.7152*light.g + 0.0722*light.b));
vec4 emission = texture2D(emissionTexture, _surface.diffuseTexcoord) * lum;
_output.color += emission;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of free tools for converting GLSL to MSL automatically.

For instance [Shader Playground](http://timjones.io/blog/archive/2018/05/19/introducing-shader-playground).

And both [MoltenVK](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK) and [MoltenGL](https://moltengl.com/moltengl/) contain automatic GLSL to MSL converters.